# Chemnum with pdfLaTeX

Tags: pdftex, auto-pst-pdf, chemnum

I am trying to get replacement feature in .eps files that bases on psfrag in chemnum to work with pdfLaTeX in Overleaf. I know that I need a package such as auto-pst-pdf, epstopdf, eps-to-pdf or even pstool (which is designed to work with psfrag). I have read through a lot of StackExchange posts however, I was not able to get it to work in Overleaf.[image: output when compiled with pdaflatex]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, openany]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %output font encoding for international characters

\usepackage[crop=off,runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}

\usepackage{chemnum}

\usepackage{bpchem}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \chemmacros_load_module:n #1 {} %ghs wont function without it
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{ghsystem} %for ghs symbols and senteces

\title{test}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{scheme}
    \centering

    \replacecmpd{comp1}
    \replacecmpd{comp2}
    \replacecmpd{comp3}
    \includegraphics{overview.eps}
    \caption{A test to make the numbering work}
    \label{sc:overview}
\end{scheme}

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try using `\includegraphics[draft]{overview.eps}`?

Comment: @campa Not in case of using an eps with auto-pst-pdf and chemnum.

Comment: Have you enabled shell-escape as explained in section 8 of the `chemnum` manual?  I don't know how or whether Overleaf provides enabling of shell-escape. Have you tested the example in section 8 of the `chemnum` manual with the PS file provided as part of the `chemnum` doc? Does it work? Sometimes replacing does not work, because of the EPS file doesn't really use text, that could be replaced. So to really test, we would need the used EPS file.

Comment: It would only work with TeX Live version 2020. I used another method get it to work in version 2022 by using `pstool` instead of auto-pst-pdf. Instead of using `\replacecmpd` I used `\psfrag{TMP#}{\cmpd{X}}`. This method is not as convenient but so far I had no problems with it. Only the formatting of the numbers is quite odd and I am only able to change it primitively with `\setchemnum{format=\bfseries\sffamily}` in the preamble. Perhaps someone knows a better method?